# VB.net Published Application Using Click Once, How to Get Updated Version

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

I have a program written in VB that I publish to a network drive. I am running the application on another server on my network.

Everything is working great, my goal is now to display a dialog to the user if the application has been updated.

The code for checking this is shown below.

```vb
If ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed Then
    Dim deployment As ApplicationDeployment = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment

    If deployment.CheckForUpdate() Then
        Dim currentVersion As Version = deployment.CurrentVersion
        Dim updatedVersion As Version = deployment.UpdatedVersion

        lbl_mes_text.Text = "Client Version [" & updatedVersion.ToString() & "] is now available. " &
            vbCrLf &
            "Current Version [" & currentVersion.ToString() & "] " &
            vbCrLf &
            "Please exit the dialog and login again."

        If (Not pnl_New_Dialog.Visible) Then pnl_New_Dialog.Visible = True
    End If
End If
```

So I know it is working correctly, because when I publish a new version, the CheckForUpdate() does return true, and I get my popup.

The issue is my string for the popup I want to say

> "Client Version [new version] is now available. Current Version [current version]"

So the users can see the version number of the new version and the current version. The issue I am getting is that both versions are being populated with the current version, and my popup looks like this.

[PopUp Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azJBq.png)

I am trying  to get my [new version] section of my popup to show the latest version. For the image attached the latest version is 0.0.0.52, but it only shows the .51 version.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. It is not as intuitive as one would think.

You must call the `deployment.Update()` method before grabbing the versions.

```vb
Dim deployment As ApplicationDeployment = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment

If deployment.CheckForUpdate() Then
    If (Not pnl_New_Dialog.Visible) Then
        deployment.Update()

        Dim currentVersion As Version = deployment.CurrentVersion
        Dim updatedVersion As Version = deployment.UpdatedVersion

        lbl_mes_text.Text = "Client Version [" & updatedVersion.ToString() & "] is now available. " &
            vbCrLf &
            "Current Version [" & currentVersion.ToString() & "] " &
            vbCrLf &
            "Please exit the dialog and login again."

        pnl_New_Dialog.Visible = True
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Except for a message,

```
    If My.Application.IsNetworkDeployed AndAlso My.Application.Deployment.CheckForUpdate() Then
        My.Application.Deployment.Update()
    End If
```